# why android studio showing error "Error:(38, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found"

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, google-play-services, admob

This is my gradle.build on app given below it shows error:

> Error:(38, 0)  Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Is there any answer?

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.admin.youfame"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
   }
       buildTypes {
    release {
   minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard- rules.pro'
    }
}
}
  repositories {
   mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
   compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3- rev152-1.21.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
   }

      apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can you refactor your code please?

Comment: Make sure that u have added the   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'  in project gradle

Comment: i tried that but it shows another error that

Comment: it shows error that the google services.json file is missing

Comment: Please fix up the formatting of your question. It makes no sense in its current form

Comment: have you updated versions of google services and repository ???

Answer (score 1):

Add in your top-level `build.gradle` the google play services plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        //...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }
}
```

Then you have to add in your module the  `google-services.json` file

```
root
|--module
|----google-services.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the code apply plugin:

```
com.google.gms.google-services
```

and it works.